# handling external links in swift UIWebKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, webkit

I'm working on a webview using swift 4.
I'm loading local html files, in these pages are some links to other websites, but once I click on any of them I want to load them in safari or default browser instead of the WebView (browser).

my webView is called "browser"

Here are my ViewController.swift codes:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var browser: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let htmlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "kusrc/index", ofType: "html")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlpath!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    browser.load(request)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





}
```

Could somebody help me out? most of the results in google were not what I needed...

Is there the possibility to make an if sentence, where it gets asked if the stringprefix ="http:// or https://" then open safari, otherwise "browser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this delegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)

            return
        }

        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

If you want to differentiate according the `URL` scheme, you can use `URLComponents` to split the URL in its parts.

```
let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
if components?.scheme == "http" || components?.scheme == "https" {
    // insert your code here
}
```

// edit (a bit more detailed):

1. import `WebKit` on the very top of your class: `import WebKit`
2. Make your class compliant to the `WKNavigationDelegate`, by adding it behind the parent class: `class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate`
3. Assign your class to the navigation delegate of the WKWebView: `browser.navigationDelegate = self`
4. Add the above code to your class

A gist of how your class should look like in the end: [WKWebView open links in Safari](https://gist.github.com/kevenbauke/d449718a5f268ee843f286db88f137cc)

And here is a very nice tutorial about the topic: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-control-the-sites-a-wkwebview-can-visit-using-wknavigationdelegate

Comment: I must to be honest, I'm actually developing android apps and it's my first time to develope on swift. sorry for this dumb question, but where shall I add all this?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly does not work and maybe share the URL you are handling?

Comment: I copy pasted these codes https://gist.github.com/kevenbauke/d449718a5f268ee843f286db88f137cc

Comment: Maybe too early ;) Try again, I was still editing the file.

Comment: I'm trying to open a webpage https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thejami.kurvenuntersucher but it still opens it in the webview and not in safari

Comment: I did it again, and there are some errors. 1. I can't set browser.delegate, WKWebView has no member "delegate" and it still navigates the links in the webview

Comment: Sry. It should have been `browser.navigationDelegate = self`, I edited the gist.

Comment: That's now working, but. once I run the app, an error pops "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, the error is no longer in the viewcontroller.swift file but in AppDelegate.swift